# How to find a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$, where the coordinates of a vector $\vec{v}=[2, -1, 4]$ are $[-2,3,0]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

From the definition, I assigned a set of vectors $\{\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}\}$ as a basis to the vector $\vec{v}$, in this case:
$$\vec{v}=[2,-1,4]=-2\cdot\vec{a}+3\cdot\vec{b}+0\cdot\vec{c}$$
We can also expand $\{\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}\}$ and obtain:
$$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\4\end{bmatrix}=-2\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}+3\cdot\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}+0\cdot\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore
$$\left[\begin{matrix}-2a_1+3b_1+0c_1\\-2a_2+3b_2+0c_2\\-2a_3+3b_3+0c_3\end{matrix}\left|\,\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\4\\\end{matrix}\right.\right]
$$
Since the coordinates are the same in each row, I treat them as variables and the vectors as the coefficient, in this case, we obtain a system of equations, where the coefficient matrix would be
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a_3&b_3&c_3\end{bmatrix}$$
Using Cramer's Method, I get three more matrices
$$D_1=\begin{bmatrix}2&b_1&c_1\\-1&b_2&c_2\\4&b_3&c_3\end{bmatrix}, D_2=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&2&c_1\\a_2&-1&c_2\\a_3&4&c_3\end{bmatrix}, D_3=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&b_1&2\\a_2&b_2&-1\\a_3&b_3&4\end{bmatrix}\text{, and, }\\-2=\tfrac{\left|D_1\right|}{\left|A\right|}, 3=\tfrac{\left|D_2\right|}{\left|A\right|}, 0=\tfrac{\left|D_3\right|}{\left|A\right|}, \left|A\right|\neq0$$
I did not proceed any further as the values for the vectors could've been found via solving the equations.
But I still want to know if there is anything I missed. I am not sure if I solved it correctly. Do I need to follow any further steps?

Comment: Maybe you're working too hard. You could let the first vector in the basis be $(1,0,0)$, let the second be $((2,-1,4)+2(1,0,0))/3$, and let the 3rd basis vector be anything linearly independent of the first two, such as their cross product.

Comment: You need just to find one basis so better be specific from the start, the general case seems not requested :-)

Comment: I wonder if you could use any info from [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-Ax-b-when-x-and-b-are-known-n-dimensional-vectors-but-the-n-x-n-matrix-A-is-unknown) to help you?

Comment: @5Nik I don't understand how it works. $[2,-1,4]$ and $[-2,3,0]$ are not of the same magnitude. Do you mean to find a basis with a scaled metric? Or do you mean to find a basis with displaced origin?